# Cannot iterate over abstract Set before it has been constructed (initialized)

Tags: python, pyomo

In an abstract Model in pyomo, I want to define a new parameter in the following way:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
from coopr.pyomo import *
from objbrowser import *
import os
model = AbstractModel()

model.F = Set()
model.N_f = Set(dimen=2)
model.arcs = Set(dimen=2)
model.l_fmn = Param(model.arcs)
model.d_f = Param(model.F)

for k in model.F:
    for i1 in model.N_f[k]:
        for i2 in model.arcs[k]:
            def maker_fn(model):
                if model.arcs[k].index(i2) < model.N_f[k].index(i1):
                    return  sum(model.l_fmn[k,i2] + model.d_f[k])
                else:
                    return model.d_f[k]

            model.r_fn[k,i1] = Param(initialize=maker_fn)
```

What I want to do with these loops here is to define a parameter model.r_fn with form Param(model.N_f), I mean, a parameter with one value for each of the elements of model.N_f, which has the value at each element of model.l_fmn + model.d_f if the index at model.arcs[k] is lower than the index at model.N_f[k], and if it is not lower, let the value be the same of model.d_f.

I don't know if this is the proper way to stablish the loops and the def function to create a param, but the problem I get when I execute this is:

"RuntimeError: Cannot iterate over abstract Set 'F' before it has been constructed (initialized)."

I have tried different things and I still don't know why I get this error.

So I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to fix this error and also the proper way of making the function I want to do work propertly in order to get the parameter.

Thank you all very much in advance.

The .dat file is the following:

```
set F := f1 f2 f3;

set N_f :=
f1 "q(a)"
f1 a
f1 b
f1 C
f2 A
f2 "q(A)"
f2 e
f2 B
f3 B
f3 "q(b)"
f3 f
f3 C;

set arcs :=
f1 "(A,q(A))"
f1 "(q(A),a)"
f1 "(a,b)"
f1 "(b,C)"
f2 "(A,q(A))"
f2 "(q(A),e)"
f2 "(e,B)"
f3 "(B,q(B))"
f3 "(q(B),f)"
f3 "(f,C)";

param l_fmn :=
f1 "(A,q(A))" 0
f1 "(q(A),a)" 5
f1 "(a,b)" 8
f1 "(b,C)" 1
f2 "(A,q(A))" 0
f2 "(q(A),e)" 5
f2 "(e,B)" 7 
f3 "(B,q(B))" 0
f3 "(q(B),f)" 3
f3 "(f,C)" 3;

param d_f :=
f1 1
f2 1
f3 17;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that set `F` is not defined in your .dat file, you call it `K`. You should put `set F := f1 f2 f3;` in your first line instead.

Comment: I copied it wrong in the question, in the code it is well written, F is defined in the .dat by "f1 f2 f3" but I get that error despite having it defined in the .dat file. Mabye I have to write something else in the main code but I don't know why I am still getting this error.